# Populate Combo Box with results of dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel 'transfer file' to process raw tables into another format for consumption through Power Apps.

I have a range of cells with a list of extensions for files listed by row.

I want the extensions inserted/added into a combobox in a userform.

We start with my listing of file extensions I pull from a OneDrive file with the following code.

```vb
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("Not important URL to one drive location")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name
    i = i + 1
Next oFile
End Sub
```

This returns my file extensions in column A of sheet 2.

I want to add those file extensions to a combo box for a user to select.

My code thus far:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

UserForm1.Show

lastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
With UserForm1.ComboBox1
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ComboBox1.AddItem Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `cbCategory`? I am guessing you can leave that out, and just call `AddItem`.

Comment: DS_London I have edited the post as suggested, and changed the .Show location.  The combobox still is empty though.

Comment: DS_London, your comment inspired me and here is teh solution that I want to give you credit for...

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
lastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    With UserForm1.ComboBox1
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            ComboBox1.AddItem Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)
        Next
    End With

UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Comment: The `With` statement removes the need to 'qualify' the AddItem call with an object, so you can write `.AddItem Sheet2.Cells(i,1)` See reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement

Comment: Thank you so much! DS_London for President, or Prime Minister!!!